# NodeJS compiler server/client static class inheritance error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, babeljs

I have a few issues.
I'm currently coding a CMS using React for client side with Webpack and Express for server side with Babel.

What I am trying to do is setup a common `X-CSRF-Token` header on the `axios` module on my client side that gets a token generated from a shared file that the server side uses to verify the token.

The problem is that, when I use two different compilers, the static class inheritance doesn't work, so instead of verifying the existing generated token inside the class, it instead generates a whole new.

Would it work if I somehow managed to use the same Webpack config for both server and client side?

When I start up my server, I use this npm script:
`nodemon --watch server --exec babel-node -- server/index.js`

For the client side, I use Webpack HMR with this config:

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'

const clientPath = path.join(__dirname, 'client')
//const bundlePath = path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'js')

export default {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    clientPath
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: '/',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: clientPath,
      loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  }
}
```

**server/index.js**
So in my server index file, I send the index.html file that has the bundle.js required.

```
import express, {app} from './app'
import config from '../config.json'
import path from 'path'
import './database'

const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static')

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(err.statusCode || err.status || 500)
      .send(err.data || err.message || {})
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

app.use('/api', require('./api'))

app.use(express.static(staticPath))

app.get('*', (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, 'index.html'))
)

app.listen(config.port, () =>
  console.log(`Listening on port: ${config.port}`)
)
```

**server/app.js**
And in my server app file I initialize the Webpack and other middleware:

```
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware'
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import expressSession from 'express-session'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import path from 'path'

import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config'

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)
export const router = express.Router()

export const app = express()
  .use(cors())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(expressSession({
    secret: 'test',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
  }))
  .use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    hot: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
  }))
  .use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

export default express
```

**utils/csrf.js** 
This is the CSRF file that's shared between both the client and server side.

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'
import randomString from 'crypto-random-string'

import config from '../config.json'

export default class CSRF {

  static secret: String
  static csrf: String
  static tokenCounter: Number

  static generate(counter: Number = 10): String {
    if (!this.csrf || this.tokenCounter >= (config.csrf.counter || counter)) {
      // after 10 or defined times the token has been used, regenerate it
      this.secret = config.csrf.secret !== '' ? config.csrf.secret : randomString(8)
      let token = randomString(12)
      this.csrf = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(token, this.secret).toString()

      this.tokenCounter = 0
    }

    return this.csrf
  }

  static verify(req: Object): Boolean {
    const csrf = req.headers['x-csrf-token']
    if (!csrf) return false

    this.tokenCounter++

    //const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(csrf, this.secret)
    //const decrypted = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)

    return csrf === this.csrf
  }

}
```

So in my **client/index.js** file, I setup the `axios` header like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'

import Routes from './routes'
import store from './store'
import config from '../config.json'
import CSRF from '../utils/csrf'

if (config.production) process.NODE_ENV = "production"

axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = CSRF.generate()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Routes />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

Then from a `Redux` action I send a post request:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function userSignUpRequest(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.post('/api/users/signup', data)
                .then(res => res.data)
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.status) {
                        resolve(data.user)
                    } else {
                        reject(data.errors)
                    }
                })
        })
    }
}
```

And in **server/api/users/signup** I verify the `CSRF` token:

```
import Users from '../../database/models/users'
import Validate from '../../../utils/validate'
import CSRF from '../../../utils/csrf'

export default async function (req, res) {
  if (!CSRF.verify(req)) {
    return res.status(405).json({ status: false, reason: 'Invalid CSRF token' })
  }

  const {validationErrors, isValid} = Validate.registerInput(req.body)

  if (!isValid) {
    res.json({ status: false, errors: validationErrors })
  } else {
    const {email, username, password} = req.body
    let errors = {}


    try {
      await Users.query().where('mail', email)
    } catch(err) {
      errors.email = 'This email is already taken'
    }

    try {
      await Users.query().where('username', username)
    } catch(err) {
      errors.username = 'This username is already taken'
    }

    if (Validate.isObjEmpty(errors)) {
      Users.query().insert({
        mail: email, username, password
      })
        .then(user => res.status(200).json({ status: true, user }))
        .catch(errors => res.json({ status: false, errors }))

    } else {
      res.json({ status: false, errors })
    }
  }
}
```

Whole source code: [Github](https://github.com/marcus-sa/stormcms/tree/dev)